# Nginx: Redirect everything to http://example.com

Tags: nginx

I would like to understand what the proper Nginx configuration is to redirect everything to http://example.com/ ... Namely:

1. https://example.com/
2. https://www.example.com/
3. http://www.example.com/

Need to redirect to http://example.com/ automatically. How do I configure that?

Comment: This question is asked and answered literally every week or so. For https you'll need valid certificate, other than this it's 3-line config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;
    <your other nginx settings>
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Your first server block is a redirect loop

Comment: The last line of the first block should look like this:
`return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;`
    
Thanks to @Brian Bowles for catching it. This is a winner otherwise.

Comment: I also changed the third block to use this: `return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;`